# Bluetooth LE device using bluez python dbus interface

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I use this BLE advertising example on my Raspberry Pi

https://scribles.net/running-ble-advertising-example-code-on-raspbian-stretch/

My question is when the other central wants to connect with me, can I know who they are before they connect? And can I reject the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Central device performs scan; LE peripheral only advertises. So, You can not do what you want. But.,

Once the central device establish connection a DBus signal is emitted from org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager interface with **Connected** Property of org.bluez.Device1 interface set to true.

You can use **Blocked** DBus property from org.bluez.Device1 interface to block connections from a central device from next connection. This causes your hardware to ignore any connection request from that device.

But Bluetooth Low Energy random LE addressing feature makes it tough to block devices with particular MAC address. Because central device can try to connect with random MAC on every connection.

Comment: Thank for your help.
I will try to use Blocked DBus property from org.bluez.Device1 interface.
Thank you.